# how to change content of dynamically generated button with MenuFlyout in windows phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am generating a button dynamically containing MenuFlyout.

```
       public Button createButton(string name, String[] value)
    {
        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.Name = name;
        MenuFlyout m = createMenu(value);
       bt.Click +=  (sender, e) => { Bt_Click(sender, e, m, name); };

        return bt;
    }
private void Bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, MenuFlyout m, string name)
    {

        m.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
        buttonclicked = name;
    }

    public MenuFlyout createMenu(string[] value)
    {
        MenuFlyout m = new MenuFlyout();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            MenuFlyoutItem mn = new MenuFlyoutItem();
            mn.Text = value[i];
            mn.Click += Mn_Click;
            m.Items.Add(mn);
        }
        return m;
    }

    private void Mn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

now I want that when any Menu Flyout item is clicked the button should change its content.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540343/how-to-change-button-content-when-clicked-in-xaml

Comment: no, actually i am not getting how to refer to that button. because that is dynamically generated. @Barnstokkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are tracking the name of the button that has been clicked. With that you can search the xaml tree for it and change the content that way.

Looking for a visual element is done with the `VisualTreeHelper` 
All details can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper

It has a nice code snippet at the bottom, with that you can find all 'Buttons' on a page and from that list take the one with the correct name and change it's content.
Something similar like this [UWP: changing the (text) style of a ListBoxItem Element in c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765213/uwp-changing-the-text-style-of-a-listboxitem-element-in-c-sharp-code)

```
internal static void FindChildren<T>(List<T> results, DependencyObject startNode)
  where T : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(startNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(startNode, i);
        if ((current.GetType()).Equals(typeof(T)) || (current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            T asType = (T)current;
            results.Add(asType);
        }
        FindChildren<T>(results, current);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping and What is the "startNode" supposed to be

Comment: That is another UI element on the page... or the page itself. Take a look at the link to the other SO question it has an example of the usage - it uses a listbox there. But in your case use the Grid where the button is in ( if there is a main grid )

Comment: ok thanks but it is not updating the content of button. while debuging every thing seems right

Comment: Hmm and changing the content manually in code just to test if that works? So if you debug, you get the correct button with the 'old' content value?

Comment: i have tried by hardcoding but it is nor working any solution for this? @Depechie